# How to backup Azure SQL that will withstand deletion of azure server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine, database-backups, azure-sql-server

Azure SQL has built in backups. If the SQL database and server are deleted from within the Portal these backups are lost.

What is best practice for backing up Azure SQL that will withstand deletion of the server from the portal.

I have manually exported the database to a storage location, however Azure says that this should not be used as a backup. Why should it not be used and what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a direct control over your backups, then the best mechanism is fairly straight forward.

1. Create a copy of your database. This ensures no active transactions because it's a copy.
2. Use the BACPAC process to export the copy of the database. BACPAC doesn't respect transactions, this is why we created a copy.
3. Store this where ever you want.
4. Drop the copy of the database because you're paying for that while it exists.

You can use the BACPAC to import into a new Azure database, or you can import it into a VM in Azure, AWS, or locally.

Comment: Do you have a guide for importing BACPAC into a fresh DB ? This seems the best solution.

Comment: I haven't written one myself, but Microsoft has one online here that uses the wizard in SSMS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database

Comment: I'd say this is better. They show how to use the Portal, or better still, PowerShell to get it done: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import

Comment: This is what I was already doing, they just said it was not recommended.

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded I've been on the road. Not recommend for what? As the only backup process? Sure. I agree. Their backup process and it's ability to do a point in time restore is much better. As a mechanism for ensuring that you have a separate copy of the database independent of theirs? Yeah, this is the one way to get it done currently.

Comment: Yeah i guess I just wanted to make sure this was the best method for a second layer or backups. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure SQL has built in backups. If the SQL database and server are
>   deleted from within the Portal these backups are lost.

Yes,If you delete the Azure SQL server that hosts SQL Databases, all databases that belong to the server are also deleted and cannot be recovered. You cannot restore a deleted server.

> What is best practice for backing up Azure SQL that will withstand
>   deletion of the server from the portal.

If your Azure SQL Server has been deleted, you need to create a support ticket to  restore the databases.

When you really need to delete a SQL sever and then try to back up it, You can [**configure the Azure Recovery Services vault to store Azure SQL database backups**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-backup-retention-configure) and then recover a database using backups retained in the vault using the Azure portal or PowerShell.

> Why should it not be used and what should I be doing instead?

I think you can export your database to your local storage , but it's complex to restore it to Azure. Also, it may change some information of your SQL database and may need migration to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no real answer to this, you can use any backup method you like. Its mostly a personal preference.

But the easiest way (probably) is using Azure Backup Vault to do long term backups (which is a native way for Azure). Its pretty easy to configure (next\next\next) and it is not connected to the Azure SQL Server, so when you delete the server the backups are there.